# Tomcat chef recipe is not using the right version

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, chef-infra

How can I correctly tell the tomcat chef recipes to use the version 8 of tomcat.

I try these lines in a attributes/default.rb file of a recipe depending on tomcat:

```
override['tomcat']['base_version'] = 8
default['tomcat']['base_version'] = 8
raise node['tomcat']['base_instance']
```

It displays

```
RuntimeError
------------
tomcat6
```

How can I get tomcat recipe using installing tomcat8?

Comment: See: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat/issues/129 It looks like you may need to use an additional wrapper recipe. Follow the links in the comments

Comment: You can add an [`include_attribute`](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-file-ordering) statement in your attribute file to force the reload of the tomcat attribute file with an overrided base_version (use force.default or override, staying at default would reset the base_version.

Comment: I added `include_attribute "tomcat"` after `override` but raise still displays tomcat6.

Comment: No luck in this case, you'll have to get the tomcat attribute file and redefine each attribute as shown in the ticket @DisplayNameismissing has linked in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the override using a role? For example:

[How to customise a tomcat recipe in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073884/how-to-customise-a-tomcat-recipe-in-chef/31083781#31083781)

It's also worth noting that the java cookbook [uses packages to install tomcat](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L51) but "tomcat8" is currently not available yet in the Ubuntu repositories...

Hope this helps