# Chef solo can't find cookbook during kitchen test run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf, test-kitchen

I'm trying to add a Test Kitchen for a bunch of cookbooks that we use to provision a Jenkins CI instance.

We use Berkshelf to manage dependencies. The file structure is as follows:

```
|   .gitignore
|   .kitchen.yml
|   Berksfile
|   Berksfile.lock
|   bootstrap.sh
|   chefignore
|   metadata.rb
|   provision.sh
|   readme.md
|   solo.json
|   solo.rb
|   tree.txt
|   VERSION
|   
+---.kitchen
|   |   default-ubuntu-1404.yml
|   |   
|   +---kitchen-vagrant
|   |   \---kitchen-chef-jenkins-default-ubuntu-1404
|   |       |   Vagrantfile
|   |       |   
|   |       \---.vagrant
|   |           \---machines
|   |               \---default
|   |                   \---virtualbox
|   |                           action_set_name
|   |                           id
|   |                           index_uuid
|   |                           private_key
|   |                           synced_folders
|   |                           
|   \---logs
|           default-centos-71.log
|           default-ubuntu-1404.log
|           kitchen.log
|           
+---site-cookbooks
|   +---ant
|   |   |   .gitignore
|   |   |   .kitchen.yml
|   |   |   Berksfile
|   |   |   CHANGELOG.md
|   |   |   chefignore
|   |   |   CONTRIBUTING.md
|   |   |   LICENSE
|   |   |   metadata.rb
|   |   |   README.md
|   |   |   TESTING.md
|   |   |   Thorfile
|   |   |   
|   |   +---attributes
|   |   |       default.rb
|   |   |       
|   |   +---providers
|   |   |       library.rb
|   |   |       
|   |   +---recipes
|   |   |       default.rb
|   |   |       install_package.rb
|   |   |       install_source.rb
|   |   |       
|   |   +---resources
|   |   |       library.rb
|   |   |       
|   |   \---templates
|   |       \---default
|   |               ant_home.sh.erb
|   |               
|   +---haxe_cookbook
|   |   |   CHANGELOG.md
|   |   |   metadata.rb
|   |   |   README.md
|   |   |   
|   |   \---recipes
|   |           default.rb
|   |           
|   \---mbp-jenkins
|       |   Berksfile
|       |   Berksfile.lock
|       |   CHANGELOG.md
|       |   chefignore
|       |   metadata.rb
|       |   README.md
|       |   
|       +---recipes
|       |       default.rb
|       |       
|       +---resources
|       |   |   commons-net-3.3.jar
|       |   |   
|       |   +---css
|       |   |       style.css
|       |   |       
|       |   +---images
|       |   |       logo-mbp.png
|       |   |       web.png
|       |   |       
|       |   \---js
|       |           scripts.js
|       |           
|       \---templates
|           +---default
|           |   |   config.xml
|           |   |   
|           |   \---secrets
|           |           hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.consoleAnnotator
|           |           hudson.model.Job.serverCookie
|           |           hudson.util.Secret
|           |           jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty.seed
|           |           jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol.secret
|           |           master.key
|           |           org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.mac
|           |           org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.KEY
|           |           
|           \---emails
|                   build-complete.html.groovy
|                   build-started.html.groovy
|                   
\---test
    \---integration
        \---default
```

Executing:

```
kitchen converge default-ubuntu-1404
```

Results in the following error:

```
    [2015-08-24T09:13:24+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook mbp-jenkins not found. If you're loading mbp-jenkins from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
[2015-08-24T09:13:24+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Which suggests that chef-solo can't find the cookbook mbp-jenkins. I would expect it to find it though as we define the cookbook paths in the solo.rb file as follows:

```
root = File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

file_cache_path 'cache'
cookbook_path [root + "/cookbooks", root + "/site-cookbooks",root + "/berks-cookbooks"]
```

Not really sure what is going wrong here so any suggestions would be appreciated

**Update:**

I have tried using the chef zero provisioner, that however gives me the output:

```
================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: mbp-jenkins

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* mbp-jenkins::default
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the chef_zero provisioner instead? I suspect your problem is because chef solo does not run Berkshelf, which would explain the missing cookbooks.

For example see:

[How to customise a tomcat recipe in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073884/how-to-customise-a-tomcat-recipe-in-chef/31083781#31083781)

## Update

The issue appears to be that the cookbooks in the site-cookbooks directory is not be copied over to the target machine.

Seems to me the simplest and best fix is to include the local cookbooks in your Berksfile as follows:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'ant',           path: 'site-cookbooks/ant'
cookbook 'haxe_cookbook', path: 'site-cookbooks/haxe_cookbook'
cookbook 'mbp-jenkins',   path: 'site-cookbooks/mbp-jenkins'

metadata
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue - it looked as though the Berkshelf run completed successfully. The cookbook that cannot be found is actually in the /site-cookbooks/ directory and isn't a dependency that is managed by Berkshelf.

I've updated my question to include the output that chef zero gives me. I think the issue is that chef isn't looking in the /site-cookbooks/ directory to find the mbp-jenkins cookbook

Comment: @PiX06 Perhaps you should include all cookbooks in your berksfile?