# Kitchen: add a role to a node

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

One of our app uses gunicorn and is configured via a chef cookbook.

The cookbook has some attributes, one of them is the gunicorn version:

```
grep 'version' attributes/default.rb
default['myapp']['gunicorn']['version'] = '19.1.1'
```

I want to use version `19.3.0` only if a node is part of a specific role. I created a role and gave it an attribute:

```
cat ../../roles/gunicorn-19.3.0.rb
name 'gunicorn-19.3.0'

default_attributes(
  'mcnulty' => {
    'gunicorn' => {
      'version' => '19.3.0'
    }
  }
)
```

Given that roles attribute get precedence over cookbook attributes, this *should* work. right??

Now I'd like to test that with kitchen. In our `kichen.yml` we already have a `default` suite, I copied and created a `gunicorn-19.3.0` suite:

```
- name: gunicorn-19.3.0
    roles_path: '../../roles'
    run_list:
      - recipe[apt]
      - recipe[build-essential]
      - recipe[myapp]
    attributes: &attributes
      myapp:
        gunicorn:
          query:
            timeout: 5
            workers: 2
            sockdir: /var/run/myapp
          web:
            timeout: 5
            workers: 2
            sockdir: /var/run/myapp
```

Now I cannot figure out how to mimic the fact this host is part of the `gunicorn-19.3.0` role...

Any help is appreciated.

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your role under the test/integration directory and it will be picked up automatically by chef-zero:

```
├── .kitchen.yml
└── test
    └── integration
        └── roles
            └── myrole.json
```

Then in your kitchen file create two test suites, one using the cookbook recipe, the other using the role:

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[mycookbook::default]
  - name: withrole
    run_list:
      - role[myrole]
```

Example using role to manage tomcat attributes:

- [How to customise a tomcat recipe in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073884/how-to-customise-a-tomcat-recipe-in-chef/31083781#31083781)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark, that was spot on:

```
cat test/integration/roles/gunicorn-19-3-0.json
{
  "name": "gunicorn-19-3-0",
  "override_attributes": {
    "myapp": {
      "gunicorn": {
        "version": "19.3.0"
      }
    }
  }
}

cat .kitchen.yml
 - name: gunicorn-19.3.0
    #roles_path: '../../roles'
    run_list:
      - recipe[apt]
      - recipe[build-essential]
      - recipe[python]
      - recipe[myapp::default]
      - role[gunicorn-19-3-0]
    attributes: &attributes
      myapp:
        gunicorn:
          query:
            timeout: 5
            workers: 2
            sockdir: /var/run/myapp
          web:
            timeout: 5
            workers: 2
            sockdir: /var/run/myapp
```

After a `kitchen converge`, gunicorn 19.3.0 is installed.
thanks!